# are global variables available anywhere in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, global-variables

res.locals.user

Would I have access to "user" inside any component to toggle visibility of other components.  Such as: if user exists, render LogOut button component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it's not a good practice to use global variables. If u want to use the variable in your component or its child tree, pass that as a prop to the component. More details about your component to give a precise answer.